# Using jQuery's setTimout() Function For Anchor Scrolling

Tags: javascript, settimeout, anchor-scroll

I'm still learning how to use jQuery and I have this script which smooth scrolls to anchors on my page. I would like it to wait a second before it begins scrolling, as I have a menu that needs to close. I assume I need to use the `setTimeout()` function but cannot figure out how to implement it correctly in my code below.

```js
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);

     $('html, body').stop().animate({
         'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 2
     }, 900, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
         window.location.hash = target;
     });
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is basic Javascript, nothing to do with jQuery. Everything in jQuery begins with `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the animate in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 2
    }, 900, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it after your click, within the event. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // a settimeout is a function with two parameters: a function to execute, 
        // and a time to delay. So whatever you want to do, you can wrap in what is
        // called an 'anonymous' function. Used once, then forgotten about.
        setTimeout(function(){
            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 2
            }, 900, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){

    //insert code here

}, 1000);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: if you want to refer to docs regarding `DOM` API or JS methods, there are much officials docs like mdn, msdn etc... Those guys actually implement it in browsers... and is much reliable than `w3fools`..